# How to customze UISlider to get stepps visible

Tags: ios, ios7, uislider

I want to customize my UISlider to be able to show steps like in photo attached (BTW this is a font size selector, native control from my iPhone settings). I able to set images for min and max but I can't show steps. I don't need 3rd party libraries to do this, I'm sure that it's possible to customize UISlider to have this.

[image]

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some subviews behind the slider to display the steps:

```
int numSteps = 5;
for(int i=0; i<numSteps; i++){
    CGFloat x = i*CGRectGetWidth(slider.frame)/(numSteps-1);
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, CGRectGetMidY(slider.frame)-5, 1, 10)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [slider.superview insertSubView:v belowSubview:slider];

    UILabel numberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
    numberLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [numberLabel sizeToFit];
    numberLabel.center = CGPointMake(x, CGRectGetMidY(slider.frame)+CGRectGetHeight(numberLabel.frame)/2+7);
    [slider.superview insertSubView:numberLabel belowSubview:slider];
}
```

Comment: Robert your solution works, thanks. Could you please also show how to add numbers/letters like small and big A symbols? I want to show numbers for every step.

Comment: I've modified the answer to add an Label as well. Set it whatever text you like...